# How To Allow Web Browsing Through Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-firewall

I suppose this question might seem useless at first glance, but I'm trying to lock down the outbound firewall rules on my PC.  My thinking is that if there were any malicious software on my PC, I would not want it communicating with other computers.  To this end, I really only want to allow web browser connections and remote desktop connections to be made.  The Public Profile in the Windows Firewall for my PC is set to active.  Also, all inbound and outbound connections that do not match one of the active rules are blocked.  I created a custom firewall outbound program rule that allows the program %ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe to make connections.  The rule is configured for all profiles and any protocol (which probably shouldn't be necessary).  However, IE still is unable to connect.  I'm rather lost and not sure what to do...

I tried using Procmon to troubleshoot the issue, but wasn't really sure what to look for (this is even after I applied a filter to only show events pertaining to iexplore.exe).

Thanks much in advance!

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the reason my firewall exception wasn't working was due to it being for the 64-bit version of IE, rather than the 32-bit version.  Once I changed the program that was being allowed through the firewall from %ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe to %ProgramFiles% (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe, I was once again able to connect to the Internet.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for this - rather confusing that the path shown in task manager is "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe". I did the same as you. Saved me a lot of head scratching.